# kotlin com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, okhttp

I tried to parse JSON string using OKHttp in Kotlin but it giving me following error & the app is crashing:

2019-09-30 15:27:24.871 4808-4933/com.kabelash.kotlinrepo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
        Process: com.kabelash.kotlinrepo, PID: 4808
        com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
            at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)

My MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView_main.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this);

        fetchJson()

    }

    fun fetchJson() {
        val url = "https://api.myurl.com/"

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println(body)

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val feed = gson.fromJson(body, Feed::class.java)

                runOnUiThread {
                    recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter(feed)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Request Failed")
            }
        })
    }
}

class Feed (val name: String, val created_at: String, val owner: Owner)

class Owner (val login: String, val avatar_url: String)
```

My MainAdapter.kt

```
class MainAdapter(val feed: Feed): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return feed.name.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val rowCell = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.repo_row, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(rowCell)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val fd = feed.name.get(position)
        holder.view.titleText.text = fd.toString()
    }

}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
}
```

I have spend so much time in it but still I couldn't figure it out. How could I resolve it? Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like your api returns an array of json objects and you trying to convert it to Feed Object. Am I right?

Comment: That's right.. I don't understand where it's going wrong or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API returns an array of Json objects. Therefore you need to parse it to array.

Instead of `val feed = gson.fromJson(body, Feed::class.java)` You should put `val feed = gson.fromJson(body, Array<Feed>::class.java)`

**MainAdaptor**

```java
class MainAdapter(val feed: Array<Feed>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return feed.count()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val rowCell = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.repo_row, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(rowCell)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val fd = feed.get(position)
        holder.view.titleText.text = fd.name.toString()
    }

}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
}
```

Comment: How could I call the objects in Main adapter? 'override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        //val commitTitle = commitTiles.get(position)
        val fd = feed.name.get(position)
        holder.view.titleText.text = fd.toString()
    }'

Comment: Just marked it. How could I load image url in imageview?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. where is the image view and image url?

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting image url like this: 'feed[position].owner.avatar_url' Now I want to set this to 'holder.view.proImg'. How could I achieve it?

Comment: You need to use a library like Glider, Picasso. But I usually use [nostra13](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line: `val feed = gson.fromJson(body, Feed::class.java)`. This takes the json and attempts to deserialize into the class you have provided. However, `Feed` is an object and your json is in the form of an array, so when gson deserializes it is expecting a `{` at the start. Instead, it is seeing a `[`.

There are a couple options to fix this:

- If you have access to the source of the json, modify to fit a `Feed` object.
- Change `Feed` to extend `List<T>` or `Array<T>`.
- Pass a list/array type to gson.

Comment: how could I set it to a textview in onBindViewHolder?